# I have two index funcions in two different route folders but I am getting an assertion error

Tags: javascript, flask

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsAUz.png)

I am trying to create a flask application with a basic blueprint file structure. I added an index view function in two different routes. One under main and one under transcriptApi.

Even though I mapped the blueprints to two different urls, I am getting the following assertion error:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui2hF.png)

Wouldn't the index having two different urls because of two different blueprints avoid this error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. The blueprints work properly. I just had a duplicate index function in one of my blueprints file. It was also called index.